# Git diff shows phantom changes

Tags: git

When I clone a repository on Windows, I see unstaged changes in Git status without making any working tree changes. `git diff` shows that some changes have occurred, for example

```
-tablespace development
-storage(initial 10K next 10K maxextents 999);
+tablespace &tablespace
+storage(initial &initial next &next maxextents 999);
```

However, if I edit the same file using a text editor, those files are not present.

Cloning the same repository on another (Linux) system, I do not have the same problem. This leads me to believe that there are some hooks or other preprocessing steps configured on my desktop.

I can not find any active hooks in `$GIT_DIR/hooks`, `C:\Program Files\Git\etc`, or `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw\etc`.

Using the `--no-textconv` switch for `git diff` has no effect.

`git add .` results in only 1 of the 37 "changed" files being indexed, the rest still show as unstaged changes.

I'm at my wits' end. Any ideas what might be causing Git to show these phantom differences?

Files requested:

```
# .gitattributes
*           text=auto
*.txt       text
*.vcproj    text eol=crlf
*.sh        text eol=lf
*.shl       text eol=lf
*.jpg       -text
```

and

```
# .git/config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = <repo url>
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

note also, `git config -l` shows

```
...
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
...
```

Comment: Since you specify "on windows", does this mean the repository is also sometimes handled on other platforms? If so then my psychic troubleshooting powers tells me that you have a line ending issue. Check the `git config core.autocrlf` setting - https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/ - and also check the .gitattributes file if you have it.

Comment: Looks very much like smudge/clean filters. Please show us your `.git/config` and `.gitattributes` files.

Comment: Thanks for the line ending suggestion. I am certain this is the not the problem, as the changes being displayed are not whitespace-only.

Comment: Is it possible there are some files with the same name but different cases? `foo` and `Foo`? The typical case-insensitive Windows filesystem would only be able to store one and Git might confuse it with the other. Can you give a link to the repository?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about file names differing only in case. That seems to be the problem! Unfortunately I can't link the repo, because it contains proprietary code from a vendor. Feel free to add it as answer if you'd like the credit @Schwern.

Comment: @AdamGlauser Glad that did it! I've had this problem myself on OS X. Answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible there are some files with the same name but different cases, such as `foo` and `Foo`. The typical case-insensitive Windows filesystem would only be able to store one. Git might confuse it with the other.

This is a not uncommon problem for projects which have been traditionally Unix exclusive. OS X users will experience similar problems.

A short term solution is to create a small case-sensitive filesystem. On OS X you can make a case-sensitive disk image. I'm not sure about Windows.

The long term solution is to rename the conflicting files and make it project policy to not use overlapping files. This will make the project friendlier to Windows and OS X contributors.